# Storing uni code characters in PostgreSQL 8.4 table

Tags: postgresql, unicode, utf-8

I want to store unicode characters in on of the column of PostgreSQL8.4 datat base table. I want to store non-English language data say want to store the Indic language texts. I have achieved the same in Oracle XE by converting the text into unicode and stored in the table using nvarchar2 column data type.

The same way I want to store unicode characters of Indic languages say (Tamil,Hindi) in one of the column of a table. How to I can achieve that,what data type should I use?

Please guide me, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure the database is initialized with encoding utf8. This applies to the whole database for 8.4, later versions are more sophisticated. You might want to check the locale settings too - see the manual for details, particularly around matching with LIKE and text pattern ops.

Comment: Hi Richard,Thanks,I have checked by storing ans reteriving the non-english texts it's working fine.Since I've created the DB with UTF-8 encoding.Suppose if I've created a DB with other supported enoding type for Postgres,Can I use any column data type specifically for holding non-english texts,as like we are having in Oracle nvarchar2 and if we dont have kind of data type,can I change the Encoding to UTF-8 at later point time,will not any problem to datas in the tables. Kindly need ur advice

Comment: You can store anything you like in bytea (see manual) but it's not text. To change the encoding to utf8 on a database, create a new empty db with utf8, dump the old and restore. If you were using "sql-ascii" encoding you may need to clean up the data first - invalid chars may have crept in. Any iso encoding will be translated.